# Selenium WebdriverWait for element from another element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I'm trying to use WebDriverWait to wait for an element in a panel to load

```
 WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(MyWebDriver, 10);

 By completeButton = By.Id("completeButton");

 // This waits on page level and loads the first which isn't always the correct panel.
 // How can I wait from a given panel?
 IWebElement button = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(completeButton));

 button.Click();
```

I have multiple panels and each creates the complete button when they are ready hence the need for the wait.

I am able to wait for elements on the entire page however i want to be able to wait for elements from another element.

looking at the documentation this is obviously wrong but is there something similar to this that i could do to wait for an element from a subpage, how have others got around this issue?

```
 WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(MyPanelSubElement, 10);
```

Comment: What is `MyPanelSubElement`?

Comment: It is an IWebElement, there are multiple panels on the page and i would like to be able to wait for elements to appear on those panels. As they are a repeated panel then their elements have the same ID's so I need to wait at a panel level not page level.

Comment: Actually, in Python passing WebElement instead of webDriver instance as first argument to `WebDriverWait()` works well... Did you try `WebDriverWait(MyPanelSubElement, 10);`? Any exceptions?

Comment: You can use the Explicit wait for an element until that particular panel gets loaded.

Comment: I'm using C# and I get
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'
if I pass an IWebElement rather than an IWebDriver

Comment: @Subburaj i'm not sure I understand what you are sugesting, could you show an example?

Comment: @LiamHarries: I have given some sample in the answer section. Please check and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create a WebElementWait class :

```
public class WebElementWait : DefaultWait<IWebElement>
{       
        public WebElementWait(IWebElement element, TimeSpan timeout) : base(element, new SystemClock())
        {
            this.Timeout = timeout;
            this.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NotFoundException));
        }
}
```

2.Now use it as :

```
//Find your target panel . You can use WebDriverWait to lookup this element
//while waiting on webdriver if required.
IWebElement panel  = //some code to get your container panel ;

IWebElement targetButton = new WebElementWait(panel, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)).Until(p => { return p.FindElement(By.Id("completeButton")); });
targetButton.Click();
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks this solution is exactly what I needed, worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the explicit wait for the panel section loading.Currently, `ExpectedConditions` is deprecated from the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` and newly added in `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`. Please include the below NuGet Package

**NuGet Package Needs to be Added:**

```
DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

Expected Conditions will be available in both `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` and `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`.In order to avoid the conflicts, you can assign the newly imported package in one variable and can be access the required method.

So you can do the import like this ( `using SeleniumWaitHelper = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;` ) and  ExpectedConditions can be accessed as  `SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions`

**Sample Code:**

Here, system will wait for 10 seconds until the `MyPanelSubElement` becomes visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
//DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers NuGet package needs to be added
wait.Until(SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Required Element ID")));
```

**Edit:**

You can try with some xpath in order to wait for the required panel content section loading.

I assume that you are having multiple panel with same Xapth. Consider the below sample HTML

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div class="panelContainer">
---------------------
---------------------
<button id="completeButton" class="btn">Complete</button>
-------------------
</div>
```

You can parameterize the panel index and change it based on the required panel condition.

**Sample Code:**

```
int panelIndex = 1;

By buttonPath = By.XPath("//div[@class='Panel']["+panelIndex+"]//*[@id='completeButton']");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(buttonPath));
```

Suppose, If you want to wait for the second panel button loading, then change the panel index as 2.It will wait until the button load gets completed inside the second panel.

Comment: thanks but my panel loads before its content does, each panel loads instantly but I am waiting for the content within to load

Comment: You can use the same wait condition for the content element loading also. `wait.Until(SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Required Element ID")));`

Comment: yes but i need to tell it which panel to wait for the button from, if im waiting for the button in panel 2 to load and the button in panel 1 loads then your example would return the button in the first panel. how would I tell it to only wait for the content from a given panel element?

Comment: @LiamHarries: You can use the XPath to achieve the same. I have edited the answer and given some sample. Please check. Hope this answer solves your problem.

Comment: I am using a page object model methodology so I would like to be able to code "PanelPomObject.WaitForCompleteButton();"
This would mean placing the code in the POM object for the Panel which is why I'm having this issue.